# Loaderror for mysql2 while starting ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2

I am trying to start the ruby on rails application that i had to my old mac which i transferred all data to the new one (el capitan).

I tried to bundle install, bundle update everything, the database.yml looks fine,but the application doesn't begin due to the following error.

I have two versions of mysql2, but if i delete the 0.4.2 and i try to bundle install (it installs 0.4.2) and if rails s (it requires the 0.4.2)

Any idea??

```
/Users/glouk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:314:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.2. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
```

My gem list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.12)
actionpack (3.2.12)
activemodel (3.2.12)
activerecord (3.2.12)
activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
activeresource (3.2.12)
activesupport (3.2.12)
acts-as-taggable-on (2.3.3)
afm (0.2.0)
arel (3.0.3, 3.0.2)
Ascii85 (1.0.2)
awesome_nested_set (2.1.6)
bcrypt (3.1.10)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
beanstalk-client (1.1.1)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.11.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
cancan (1.6.10, 1.6.9)
capistrano (2.15.4)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cocaine (0.5.1)
cocoon (1.2.6, 1.1.2)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.10.0, 1.6.2)
combined_time_select (1.0.1, 1.0.0)
daemons (1.2.3, 1.1.9)
deep_cloneable (1.5.1)
devise (2.2.3)
diff-lcs (1.2.5, 1.2.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
exception_notification (2.5.2)
execjs (2.6.0, 1.4.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
formtastic (2.2.1)
friendly_id (4.0.9)
galetahub-simple_captcha (0.1.5)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
has_scope (0.5.1)
hashery (2.1.0)
highline (1.7.8, 1.6.18)
hike (1.2.3, 1.2.2)
httpclient (2.7.0.1, 2.3.3)
i18n (0.7.0, 0.6.4)
impressionist (1.3.1)
inherited_resources (1.4.0)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.2.1)
jquery-turbolinks (1.0.0)
jquery_datepicker (0.4)
json (1.8.3, 1.7.7, 1.5.5)
libv8 (3.16.14.13, 3.11.8.17)
liquid (3.0.6, 2.6.1)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.25.1, 1.23)
mimemagic (0.3.0)
mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.11.2, 1.7.2)
mysql (2.9.1)
mysql2 (0.4.2, 0.3.10)
negative_captcha (0.3.2)
net-scp (1.1.0)
net-sftp (2.1.1)
net-ssh (2.6.7)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
nokogiri (1.5.9)
orm_adapter (0.5.0, 0.4.0)
paper_trail (2.7.1)
paperclip (3.4.1)
pdf-core (0.6.0)
pdf-reader (1.3.3)
polyglot (0.3.5, 0.3.3)
rack (1.4.7, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.5.1, 1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.4, 1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.3, 0.6.2)
rails (3.2.12)
rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.11)
railties (3.2.12)
rake (10.4.2, 10.0.4, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12.2, 3.9.5)
ref (2.0.0, 1.0.4)
responders (0.9.3)
roo (1.11.2)
rspec-core (2.99.2, 2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.99.4, 2.13.1)
rspec-rails (2.13.2)
ruby-ole (1.2.11.6)
ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubyzip (1.1.7, 0.9.9)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
rvm-capistrano (1.3.0)
sass (3.4.20, 3.2.8)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
simple_form (2.1.0)
smarter_csv (1.1.0, 1.0.4)
social-share-button (0.1.4)
spreadsheet (0.8.5)
sprockets (2.2.3, 2.2.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.11, 1.3.7)
the_sortable_tree (2.3.2)
therubyracer (0.12.2)
thor (0.19.1, 0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (1.4.1, 1.3.7)
treetop (1.4.15, 1.4.12)
truncate_html (0.9.3, 0.9.2)
ttfunk (1.4.0, 1.0.3)
turbolinks (1.1.1)
tzinfo (0.3.46, 0.3.37)
uglifier (2.0.1)
warden (1.2.4, 1.2.1)
will_paginate (3.0.7, 3.0.4)
xapian-ruby (1.2.21, 1.2.12)
xapian_db (1.3.2)
```

Comment: Do you mean by gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.10 ? because i did but when i run bundle install, it installs additionally the 0.4.2

Comment: What version you have mentioned in gemfile ?

Comment: gem 'mysql2', '0.4.2'

Answer (score 1):

First remove the existing mysql gem.
And then try by using following version of mysql in Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
```

Comment: This worked for me. But why? Shouldn't gem/bundler handle this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution no longer works - that version of mysql2 fails to compile against the latest MariaDB :(